# inheriting numpy.vectorize-ed functions

Tags: python, numpy

While hunting down an obscure bug, I've stumbled onto something best demonstrated by this minimal example:

```
import numpy as np

class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vF = np.vectorize(self.F)
        print "First: vF = ", self.vF

    def F(self, x):
        return x**2


class Second(First):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Second, self).__init__()
        print "Second: vF = ", self.vF

    def F(self, x):
        raise RuntimeError("Never be here.")

    def vF(self, x):
        return np.asarray(x)*2
```

I'd expect that an instance of the `Second` would have an explicitly defined `vF` method, but that does not seem to be the case:

```
arg = (1, 2, 3)

f = First()       
print "calling first.vF: ", f.vF(arg)

s = Second()
print "calling second.vF: ", s.vF(arg)
```

produces

```
First: vF =  <numpy.lib.function_base.vectorize object at 0x23f9310>
calling first.vF:  [1 4 9]
First: vF =  <numpy.lib.function_base.vectorize object at 0x23f93d0>
Second: vF =  <numpy.lib.function_base.vectorize object at 0x23f93d0>
calling second.vF: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
RuntimeError: Never be here.
```

so that it seems that `s.vF` and `f.vF` is the same object, even though `s.vF == f.vF` is `False`.

Is this an expected/known/documented behavior, and `numpy.vectorize` does not play nicely with inheritance, or am I missing something simple here? 
(sure, in this particular case the problem is easy to fix by either changing `First.vF` to a normal Python method, or just not calling `super` in the `Second`'s constructor.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with NumPy. It is a consequence of the interaction of perfectly reasonable language design decisions (and the way you decided to use the language):

- Instance attributes take precedence over class attributes. I'm sure you'll agree that this is reasonable.
- Methods are class attributes, and not special at that. I'm sure you'll agree that this is reasonable (if you don't, look into descriptors, specifically bound methods which allows `self.F` to work).
- Inherited instance attributes are attached to the same object, not to some weird "parent proxy" object or something. I'm sure you'll agree that this is reasonable.

In combination, these perfectly reasonable behaviors may yield unexpected behavior, if you do not keep the details in mind and instead work with a simplified mental model (e.g. mentally segregating methods and "data" attributes). In detail, this happens in your example:

- The respective constructor is called. This is either `First.__init__`, or `Second.__init__` which immediately calls `First.__init__`.
- Therefore, `obj.vF` is *always* the vectorized function created in `First.__init__` for all `obj`.
- However, each object's vectorized function wraps the `self.F` of the respective object. In the case of the second object, this is the `RuntimeError`-raising `Second.F`.

You should probably just use a regular `vF` method here, as this allows easy overriding by subclasses, due to the way attribute lookup works (see also: MRO).

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `numpy.vectorize` or `numpy` in general really ...

What's going on here is that `Second.__init__` calls `First.__init__` which creates an instance attribute (`vF`) out of `self.F` (which is actually an instance method wrapper around `Second.F`) and stores that as `vF` on the instance.  Now when you look up `vF`, you get the monkey-patched version rather than the original instance method `Second.vF`.